# How can i fix when Kaspersky Internet Security alert virus my code block?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, virus, kaspersky

I have to develop a project but when i enter this code block Kaspersky Internet Security alert me and delete exe file.

Here is the report:

[image]

this code i added after see virus:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow idrow in dataGridView8.Rows)
        {
            TimeSpan diftime = new TimeSpan();
            DateTime diftimson;
            diftimson = Convert.ToDateTime(idrow.Cells[1].Value);
            diftime = diftimson.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            double AradakiFark1 = diftime.Hours + Convert.ToInt32(idrow.Cells[4].Value);
            int sonuc1 = Convert.ToInt32(AradakiFark1) / 24;
            if (sonuc1 <= 3)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("3 Months Left For " + sonuc1 + " ", "ATTENTION !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                idrow.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                idrow.Cells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

False-positive. Sometimes AV software detects wrongly. It has happened to most developers at some point.

You'll have to set the .exe/project folder as trusted.

Instructions:

[Application preferences window](https://support.kaspersky.com/KIS4Mac/16.0/en.lproj/pgs/58163.htm)

and

[The Trusted Zone preferences window](https://support.kaspersky.com/KIS4Mac/16.0/en.lproj/pgs/59260.htm)

(THese are links to the official docs for said AV software.)